# VBA code needed to change filters across all worksheets within workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How can I filter all worksheets within 1 workbook by selecting a value on in a drop down list on the master tab?

I have a drop down list on tab 1 (mastertab). When I select a name in this drop down list, I want all sheets to filter a specific column to this name only.  Pictures below:

Workbook Name is "ORDER GUIDES"

Each row is a different distributors name, i have about 80 total rows. Each row/distributor has a worksheet (within same workbook) with the same layout. From the orange drop down list, when I select "PIZZA", I want every sheet to filter Column "E" to show only the "PIZZA" items.

Master Tab Table and Dropdown selection

[image]

This is what I've tried so far.  All my sheets are tables though, maybe this wont work because of Ranges?

```
Sub filterSheets()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Sheets
LastRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
ws.Range("C1:C" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="ABC"
Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Questions which are only a statement of what you want tend to get closed quickly here.  To improve your chances of getting an answer, you should explain exactly what the *problem* is, and what you've tried to fix it.  Not "I want to do X" but "I want to do X but I'm having a problem because of Y - I tried C and D but got an error K"

Comment: Oh gotcha, thanks, Tim.